# How to Match just part of a cell's value instead of an exact match in VBA for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have already written a script that works fine for exact matching, but I would like to rewrite it to allow for the user to type only part of one of the criteria. The `userform` should still recognize what row it came from on the other sheet and populate the cells with it's corresponding information. The row has to contain both `txtsearch` and `txtname` for it to be correct row found.

Sample values for `txtsearch`: Instuctor, Mentor, etc.

Sample values for `txtname`: Borkowski, Villarreal, etc.

This is what I have now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range
    Set ws = Sheets("The Goods")
    For Each cel In ws.Cells(2, 2).Resize(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If cel.Value = Me.txtname.Value And cel.Offset(, 2).Value = Me.txtsearch.Value Then
           currentrow = cel.Row
            Me.txt1.Value = cel.Offset(, 3).Value
            Me.txt2.Value = cel.Offset(, 1).Value
            Me.txt3.Value = cel.Offset(, 4).Value
            Me.txt4.Value = cel.Offset(, 5).Value
            Me.txt5.Value = cel.Offset(, 6).Value
            Me.txt6.Value = cel.Offset(, 7).Value
            Me.txt7.Value = cel.Offset(, 8).Value
            Me.txt8.Value = cel.Offset(, 9).Value
            Me.txt9.Value = cel.Offset(, 10).Value
            Me.txt10.Value = cel.Offset(, 11).Value
            Me.txt11.Value = cel.Offset(, 12).Value
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with some sample values for `txname.Value` and `txtSearch.Value`, and data in the sheet that should be a partial match?

Comment: I just edited it, I want to be able to account for people not searching for the whole names or position @BigBen

Comment: You may be able to use [`Like`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/like-operator) and wildcards. Note - don't forget an `Exit For` so you stop looping after finding a match.

Comment: Tara you could change your two textboxes `txtname` and `txtsearch` to `listboxes` and load them from columns 2 and 4. so the users can just pick the values they want to look for, instead of the users misspelling the look up values.

Comment: I like that idea and would want to do that if this wasn't a living document that people upload more information to @GMalc

Comment: You can make the `listboxes` load from dynamic ranges e.g. `ListBox1.RowSource = Range(Sheet1.Range("A2"), Sheet1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)).Address(, , , True)` so when individuals are added and the form is then opened the new names will be in the `listbox`.

Comment: Will do, thanks! @GMalc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean "only part" then the `instr` function is what you need. See below...

```
If InStr(1, cel.Value, Me.txtname.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 And  _ 
   InStr(1, cel.Offset(, 2).Value, Me.txtsearch.Value) > 0 Then
```

If you meant only to the left, this would work:

```
If Left(cel.Value, Len(Me.txtname.Value)) = Me.txtname.Value And _ 
   Left(cel.Offset(, 2).Value, Len(Me.txtname.Value)) = Me.txtname.Value Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much!